# Move hyperref colored boxes to the background?

Tags: hyperref

The colored boxes of `hyperref` links are in the foreground, which often hides punctuation. Is it possible to move the boxes to the background, so that text is written on top of it and not the other way around?

Comment: the boxes are not actually drawn by tex but by the pdf renderer based on an annotation on the link, so I think the answer is no, but they always look horrible and I'd use hyperref options to turn them off, then use colour or font change to show the link.